# Could a planet with only a population of 750 million achieve the technology to achieve hyper light travel?

Tags: technological-development

To be clear hyper light travel is not the same as FTL travel. Hyper light travel works in a way that is similar to Issac Asimov’s hyperdrive, it transports the ship into another dimension in which distance is different. (I can’t explain it any better) For arguments sake let’s say that a ship travels 10m in this dimension, it has in fact traveled 1000km in our universe. This makes long range interstellar travel feasible as one dose not need to travel at speeds that exceed C in order to travel vast distances in a matter of hours. But as it is unlikely that ship can survive in this dimension as it would probably work on different physical laws, ship would need to isolate itself from this dimension with the use of an energy shield. The ship would need to be powered by a highly efficient nuclear fusion reactor as anti matter was banned after an incident which led to the death of 200 thousand people.
I hope that that is enough info.

Comment: Welcome Prince T42. Your question has been automatically flagged to our [low quality review queue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/81693) for its length and content. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. Enjoy the site.

Comment: You would need to give us much more detail about your world - and about the "hyper light travel" for the question to be answerable.

Comment: As far as we know, FTL is unatainable no matter how many people a planet has, so it's not clear what you're asking for. You should define what kind of technologies or scientifical development it is required for you hyper light travel to work, and then probably somebody can help you with a ballpark estimation on how many people you need for that.

Comment: If you go from point A to point B faster than light would take to go from point A to point B then you have travelled from A to B faster than light. The mechanics of how you do it do not matter; all the unpleasant consequences of faster than light travel are completely agnostic about the means to travel faster than light.

Comment: So even though the ships velocity did not exceed C it still moved faster than C which is physically impossible. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

750 million is roughly double the current population of the United States, which maintains both state and commercial space flight/operations.

If the technology to travel more than 1 light year per year in realspace (FTL) - whether by hyper space or whatever other means is available to the civilisation, then it is plausible that this population level could support the necessary technological and industrial base.